# Why will my React Native app run on the iOS simulator, but not on a physical iPhone?

Tags: ios, react-native, metro-bundler, react-native-hermes

The React Native app works on iPhone (X) simulator fully, but immediately crashes on the physical version of the same phone (iOS 16.3.1). Throws this error only from the physical device:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Allports' of undefined, js engine: hermes
 LOG  Running "MyApp" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "MyApp" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

So far, I've tried:

- restarting the metro server and resetting the yarn cache
- deintegrating and reinstalling Pods into the project
- moving GestureHandlerRootView based on react-native-gesture-handler's new recommendations
- checking over everywhere that my app name is referenced to make sure it matches the registration name
- tried disabling Hermes

Here is my package.json info:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.71.4",
    "react-native-aws3": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-bidirectional-infinite-scroll": "^0.3.3",
    "react-native-big-list": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-biometrics": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.9",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.4",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.37.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.5.12",
    "react-native-numeric-input": "^1.9.1",
    "react-native-passcode-auth": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.1",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.19.0",
    "react-native-signature-capture": "^0.4.12",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-skeleton-content-nonexpo": "^1.0.13",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.7.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "rn-local-authentication": "^1.2.5",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.73.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0"
  },
```

Comment: Update/Solution: I was able to solve the issue by investigating the AllPorts variable that was breaking. Unlike in lots of other similar posts, the issue wasn't in either the registry or in the dependencies. For my specific issue, Dark mode wasn't supplying any styling variables, though Light mode was. The simulator was on Light mode and my physical device was on Dark mode. Once I added in handling for Dark mode, the issue was resolved.

Comment: How did you do that?